# Is use of "to" is correct in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

He emphasized the severity of the Covid pandemic to his son.

Comment: Yes, ***to*** is the normal preposition before the indirect object (***son***, here) with verbs like ***emphasise, tell, explain, show***, etc.

Comment: Why do you doubt this sentence?  Why do you doubt the use of "to" but not the use of "of"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is correct.

subject + verb + direct object +  + indirect object

He emphasized the severity of the Covid pandemic  his son.

subject + verb + indirect object + direct object

I sent her some flowers.

subject + verb+ direct object +  + indirect object

I sent some flowers  her.

subject + verb+ direct object +  + indirect object

He explained the poem  his son.

She gave some money  me.

I told a story  them.